# how do i get ride if blank page after deploying my vite-react app?

Tags: github-actions

am having a blank page after deploying my vite-react app to github page but it working on local host

at the json.package,
i put this at the top("homepage":"https://{my-username}.github.io/{my-reponame}

within the scripts i put this too,
"predeploy":"npm run build",
"deploy":"gh-pages -d dist"

i further went to vit .config.js to put this too,
base:"/my-reponame"

after all this done i push to github,get my live url click on it but all to no avail (getiting blank-page

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.